Java безопасно ли вызывать метод join() потока после завершения его работы, когда поток перешел в состояние TERMINATED?
В коде клиента есть тред, вся цель которого - перезапуск другого треда, для подключения к серверу, в случае если он еще не запущен или произошел обрыв связи.
Код предельно простой:
@Override
public void run() {
    while (!isInterrupted()) {
        InputThread inp = new InputThread(port, addr);
        inp.start();
        try {
            inp.join();
            try {
                sleep(TIME_WAIT_SERVER);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
            // поток был завершен, возможно отсутствует сервер, или связь прервалась
            // просто перезапустим его
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            inp.interrupt();
            try {
                inp.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

Все работает, все треды нормально отрабатывают и закрываются по закрытию программы.
Но возник вопрос, а нужна ли конструкция try .. catch вокруг sleep(TIME_WAIT_SERVER)? Если ее убрать, то при вызове извне метода interrupt() sleep прерывается и управление попадает во внешний InterruptedException.
Смущает только одно - там вызывается inp.join(), который к тому времени уже остановлен.
Собственно вопрос:
Я правильно понимаю, что раз ссылка на inp еще существует, то тред по идее пока еще в памяти и вызов inp.join() безопасен?
Или лучше оставить всё как есть?

как задать хороший вопрос

Ссылка то существует, но как реагирует уже завершённый поток на вызовы interrupt и join - это надо разбираться. Наверняка как и в других языках наверное можно проверить текущее состояние потока сначала. Хотя является ли это хорошим шаблоном проектирования, или хороший шаблон как-раз без проверки и через try/catch - это тоже вопрос. Я Java не знаю, к сожалению.

Спасибо. Значит не буду рисковать и использую try..catch. Разберусь со временем, как дойдем в изучении до потоков.

Поменяйте сами название на правильное, тут никто не запрещает много раз менять вопрос разным людям, все могут ошибаться )

Реально по шапке от модераторов можно получить только если упорно тупить и делать одну ошибку много раз. А исправление ошибок всегда только приветствуется.

Сорри, не знал что можно исправить сообщение уже после правки модератора - не заметил ссылку, как и разметку markdown (спасибо модератору - увидел как нужно оформлять). Реально непривычный форумный движок, таких еще не встречал.
